# How to fill backGround Color in line graph in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graph, line

I have drawn a line  graph.
I need to fill the background color in the below redline and the line.
How can I fill the color like the below image.

[image]

Comment: Did you create this graph with AS3? If yes - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dd9.html might be useful

Comment: @www0z0k: Yes, I draw a line graph

Comment: Do you have the points to draw a shape you need to fill?

Comment: @www0z0k:  I need to fill the color below thered line (with in the line graph)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to work around this, but they are all kind of hacky. The proper way to do it is to simply calculate. Draw two irregular shapes, one with the green, and one with the white background. They need to attach each other precisely in order to look like one whole graphic.

The hacky way I can think of is to use two DisplayObject's of any kind. Draw the very same shape inside them, then create a mask (which is above/under the red line). Then use some filter/blending/anything to color the DisplayObject with some specific color. And because of the mask - the colored shape will be cut off, so if you place the two objects one over another - it will look like the image you've provided :)

Comment: Popv: I need  draw the graph and fill the color dynamically by programatically.

Comment: You can dynamically create mask too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest calculating points to build the shape you need to fill and simply use [`Graphics.beginFill()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginFill%28%29) and [`Graphics.lineTo()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineTo%28%29) to draw it